# getImageData.data undefined in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using the following functions to grab pixel data for a clicked coordinate:

```
Utils.GetPixel = function(imgData, index)
{
    var i = index*4, d = imgData.data;
    return [d[i], d[i+1], d[i+2], d[i+3]];
};

Utils.GetPixelXY = function(gObj, x, y)
{
    return Utils.GetPixel(gObj.ImgData, y*gObj.ImgData.width+x);
};
```

Printing out some test data in Chrome/Firefox/Edge works fine but not in IE11, i'm pretty new to this so i'm a bit puzzled.

```
var p = Utils.GetPixelXY(gObj, (mx - gObj.X), (my - gObj.Y));
console.log(p[0]+" "+p[1]+" "+p[2]+" "+p[3]);
```

Chrome/Firefox/Edge:  *255 0 0 255*

IE11: *undefined undefined undefined undefined*

**UPDATE:**

I've put together a fiddle repro, sorry i took so long getting back to this.

https://jsfiddle.net/1wwtxrjp/3/

After some messing around I've discovered something peculiar where seemingly single pixels on the canvas return rgba pixel data as shown below:

[image: What on earth? o.0]

[image: What on earth2? o.0]

Comment: how is `ImgData` created in your object `gObj`? According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/ImageData there is no support for `ImageData() constructor` in IE

Comment: @both_previous_commenter, if OP was using an empty ImageData (either by the `ImageData` Constructor, or by `ctx.createImageData`, he would not have a red pixel (`[255,0,0,255]`)

Comment: What has been painted on your canvas ? Can you provide a live example ?

Comment: @Kaiido Can you describe what you mean?

Comment: Once again... What has been painted on your canvas  ? (i.e did you used drawImage ?) Can you provide a live example ? (either in the question with stacksnippet, or a fiddle, which would provide an [MCVE]). The imageData was clearly not the problem, and I believe it just adds noise to your question.

Comment: Updated question with fiddle repro

Comment: It is working in my IE11. RGBA values are available only on the image area. Other canvas area only shows undefined, even in Chrome.

Comment: I'm baffled, `Version 11.447.14393.0 Update Versions: 11.0.37 Windows 10` yields undefined for me :S

Comment: @Spark, when testing in my VM I add an issue with your gif, which seemed to taint the canvas. Can you try https://jsfiddle.net/1wwtxrjp/2 And what Sen Jacob says makes a lot of sense, you are getting only the imageData the size of your image, every coordinates out of this bound will return undefined. (your canvas is wider than the drawn image)

Comment: Same problem. Just to avoid others pointing out the canvas and test image dimensions are different i've updated it https://jsfiddle.net/1wwtxrjp/3 I have also updated the post with some strange behavior i have noticed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of utter confusion, reading and testing i discovered i had to `parseInt() to ensure that the x and y values are integers because Internet Explorer 10 and later return mouse coordinates as floats to represent fractional pixels`

Here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/1wwtxrjp/4/

I am really surprised nobody on stackoverflow pointed this out and that it took me so long to find the answer, i'd imagine a lot of people make this mistake.